# How to prevent Hashmap from overriding the same key with different values

Tags: java, hashmap

i have a code like follows where i am using a hashmap to store the details of segments created but the Hashmap is overriding the last value for all the keys.

but the response i am getting is like follows

```
0->47 {id=48 name= At_48,code=14512455......}
1->48 {id=48 name= At_48,code=14512455......}
```

i am getting all the responses overridden by last result ,how to solve this problem

Comment: You're using in every iteration the _same_ `segmentInformation`. Thus it is the only value in your map, put for every key.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, that means i should place the SegmentInformation declaration inside the for loop

Comment: Yes ... create a new `SegmentInformation segmentinformation` in every iteration step.

Comment: but there is a problem that SegmentInformation segmentinformation is also used outside the forloop so if i define it inside the forloop only how can it can be accessed outside the loop.

Comment: Why do you need it outside the loop?

Comment: I am using a try and catch block and using the segmentInformation in the catch block like this  to catch the exceptions occured                                                                                                            } catch (ValidationServiceException e) {
      segmentInformation.setError(SEGMENT_CREATION_EXCEPTION.getMessage());
      returnMap.put(segmentInformation.getAudienceId().toString(), segmentInformation);
      logger.error(TOKEN_CREATION_EXCEPTION.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      segmentInformation
          .setError(someerrormessage)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code to the question so it is readable.

Comment: can u please check now

Comment: Is `createToken()` the only method which throws potentially the both exceptions (`ValidationServiceException `, `IOException `)?

Comment: so you want to save new value and the old value under same key in hashmap?

Comment: yes both exceptions will be thrown by createToken()

Comment: no i want different keys with different values

Comment: @Ikshwak Please have a look on my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using in every iteration the *same* `segmentInformation`. Thus it is the only value in `returnMap`, put for every key.

You need to create a new `SegmentInformation` in every iteration step and put this one in the map. The problem you stated in your comment is that you are using the `segmentInformation` already before the for-loop. This is only the case if `audienceDataMap.isEmpty()`. I suggest you to separate this code from code of the loop.

```
  private Single<Map<String, CreationResponse>> createSegment(List<Integer> audienceIds) {
    try {
      createToken();
    }
    catch (ValidationServiceException e) {
      SegmentInformation segmentInformation = new SegmentInformation();
      segmentInformation.setError(SEGMENT_CREATION_EXCEPTION.getMessage());
      Map<String, CreationResponse> returnMap = new HashMap<>();
      returnMap.put(segmentInformation.getAudienceId().toString(), segmentInformation);
      logger.error(TOKEN_CREATION_EXCEPTION.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      SegmentInformation segmentInformation = new SegmentInformation();
      segmentInformation.setError(SEGMENT_CREATION_EXCEPTION.getMessage() + SEGMENT_CODE_EXIST.getMessage());
      Map<String, CreationResponse> returnMap = new HashMap<>();
      returnMap.put(segmentInformation.getAudienceId().toString(), segmentInformation);
      logger.error(SEGMENT_CREATION_EXCEPTION.getMessage());
    }

    List<ListBasedAudienceFetcher.AcAudience> audienceDataMap = audienceIds != null ?
      impl.processAudienceByIds(audienceIds) :
      impl.processAudience();

    if (audienceDataMap.isEmpty()) {
      SegmentInformation segmentInformation = new SegmentInformation();
      segmentInformation.setError(PROGRAMS_NOT_CREATED.getMessage());
      Map<String, CreationResponse> returnMap = new HashMap<>();
      returnMap.put(CREATE_PROGRAM.getMessage(), segmentInformation);
      return Single.just(returnMap);
    }

    Map<String, CreationResponse> returnMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (ListBasedAudienceFetcher.AcAudience audienceData : audienceDataMap) {
      SegmentInformation segmentInformation = new SegmentInformation();
      segmentInformation.setMemberId(memberId);
      segmentInformation.setAudienceId(audienceData.getId());
      String audienceName = getSegmentName(audienceData);
      segmentInformation.setAudienceName(audienceName);
      try {
        String createSegmentResponse = Util.post(new PayLoad()
          .setUrl(AppNexusConstants.APPNEXUS_SEGMENT_URL + "/" + memberId)
          .setRequestType(Request.POST)
          .setHeader(getAppnexusAuthHeader())
          .setPayload(createSegmentPayload(audienceData, memberId)));
        SegmentResponse segmentResponse = Util.mapper.readValue(createSegmentResponse, SegmentResponse.class);
        if (segmentResponse != null
          && segmentResponse.getResponse().getStatus() != null
          && segmentResponse.getResponse().getStatus().equals("OK")) {
          BillingData billingData = billingSegment(audienceData, segmentResponse.getResponse().getSegmentData());
          segmentResponse.getResponse().getSegmentData().setBillingData(billingData);
        } else {
          segmentInformation.setError(SEGMENT_CREATION_EXCEPTION.getMessage() + audienceData.getId());
        }
        segmentInformation.setSegmentCreationResponses(segmentResponse);
        returnMap.put(audienceData.getId().toString(), segmentInformation);
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
        segmentInformation.setError(SEGMENT_CREATION_EXCEPTION.getMessage() + SEGMENT_CODE_EXIST.getMessage());
        returnMap.put(segmentInformation.getAudienceId().toString(), segmentInformation);
        logger.error(SEGMENT_CREATION_EXCEPTION.getMessage());
      }
    }

    return Single.just(returnMap);
  }
```

Please note that I also moved the declaration of `billingData` in the if-block where it is initialized.

Comment: hi lucio i am sorry i said wrongly that exception is thrown only by createToken actually the code inside the for loop is also throwing IO exception so that should also be handled

Comment: Which method throws it?

Comment: Util class has methods that is throwing IO exception

Comment: but audienceDataMap is not accesible here now                                                   
 for (ListBasedAudienceFetcher.AcAudience audienceData : audienceDataMap) {

Comment: @Ikshwak I moved `audienceDataMap`out of the try-catch-block. Now it is visible for the for-loop.

Comment: Could you move the call of `createToken` after `if (audienceDataMap.isEmpty()) { ...}` ? If you can, this would prevent `createToken` being unnecessary executed. This would particularly pay off if `createToken` is an expensive method.

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behavior of a hash map: it doesn't care if you overwrite the values of a key that was used before. The map is just a container, how should it know that you don't want to overwrite previous values?!

If you need something else, there are two choices:

- you extend that class, and @Override the put() to check for using an already known key
- your client code that fills the map checks the presence of a key before making a call to put()

But note: you will then need a clear strategy how to deal with situations where another value was already put into the map. One solution could be to make the map value a list. And putting values for a known key results in: the new value gets added to a list.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry men I can't still post just comments, the problem you have is that the hashmethod you are using to generate you key shouldn't be returning the same hashcode, the whole idea behind hashing lost the sense if two values share the same key. change the key generator method.

regards!